# Difference between two number values where itemname is the same

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "items"

```
id       month       year       **itemname**       distmoney
 1        12         2012         chicken           20
 2        12         2012         pork              15
 3        11         2012         chicken           21
 4        11         2012         pork              15
```

I am trying to find the difference between the "distmoney" for the same itemname between two months.

Example:

ID 1, itemname chicken. month 12 distmoney is 20, while month 11 distmoney is 21. I want to be able to calculate the difference of 1 for id=1, itemname=chicken

Right now I have the php code to calculate the difference between two numbers, but I am having a tough time figuring out how to grab the previous month distmoney.

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
<?php $number1 = htmlentities($row['distmoney']) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
$number1 = $row['distmoney'];
$number2 = ????????; // THIS NEEDS TO BE THE PREVIOUS MONTH DISTMONEY VALUE
if ($number1 <= $number2) {
$difference = "(Price Lowered) Price difference of $";
$result = $number2 - $number1;
$percent = round(100.0*($number2-$number1)/$number1);
echo $difference; echo $result; echo $percent; echo "%";
} elseif ($number1 > $number2) {
$result = $number1 - $number2;
$percent = round(100.0*($number2/$number1-1));
$addition = "(Price Higher) Price difference of $";
echo $addition; echo $result; echo $percent; echo "%";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform this in SQL, then you can transform the data in columns to then get the difference:

```
select 
  itemname,
  max(case when month = 12 and year = 2012 then distmoney else 0 end) Dec2012,
  max(case when month = 11 and year = 2012 then distmoney else 0 end) Nov2012
from yourtable
group by itemname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7318/1)

The result of the query is:

```
| ITEMNAME | DEC2012 | NOV2012 |
--------------------------------
|  chicken |      20 |      21 |
|     pork |      15 |      15 |
```

Comment: This is perfect except for one thing. I do not want to display all records/group by itemname. I want to display the difference between ONE item only. I was planning on just going by where id = $id, however this would not work as it would only display the distmoney for that record, since the previous month is a different id/record. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you cannot group by the `itemname` then this will not work for your needs.  I was working under the assumption based on the sample data that you could perform that grouping.  If you need to use `id`, then you might be able to include as another column similar to this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7318/2 -- but that might not work

Comment: Would it be possible to modify your code to insert the new distmoney into a new column? From there I could just use some php to subtract the two values together.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by new distmoney?

Comment: For example, on id 1 chicken, with distmoney 20. The month before, it was 21. However, 21 is located on id 3. Is it possible to somehow get this value of 21 and insert it into a new column under id 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can just pre-process the data so that it's grouped by itemname, and store an array of the distmoney values for that item. Assuming that the data is already sorted by date correctly.

```
$diff = array();
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   if(!isset($diff[$row['itemname']])
   {
      $diff[$row['itemname']] = array();
   }
   $diff[$row['itemname']][] = $row['distmoney'];
}

foreach($diff as $itemname=>$months)
{
    if(count($months) == 2)
    {
        echo $itemname.' difference: '.$months[0]-$months[1];
    }
}
```